# PowerShell get rid of the last `n`r?

Tags: powershell, trim

I am reading lines from a text-file and want to get rid of the `n and`r and ending spaces:

```
    $g = Get-Content -Encoding ASCII $Tests -ErrorAction Stop | Out-String
    $g.Replace("`r","")
    $g.Replace("`n","")
    $g.trim()

    #Before the a.m. lines I tried unsuccessfully:
    $g.trim("`n`r ")
```

Could be the encoding - at least nothing helped?
How do I get rid of that 'editing-tail'

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace()` won't change original string, it will return a **new string** with replaced characters. Same for `Trim()`. Your code should be:

```
$g = $g.Trim("`n`r ")
```

Just to provide an example if you don't use `Trim()` your code with `Replace()` should be:

```
$g = $g.Replace("`r", "").Replace("`n", "").Trim()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it, I do $g = $(get-content...).trim("`n`r ") - perfect :)